# Call javascript function on enter of a text input, without using jquery

Tags: javascript, events, onkeyup

Is it possible to call a javascript function on enter of a text input, without using jquery?

```
<input name = 'text' type = 'text' onEnter('callJavascriptFunction')>
```

^---it would be preferable for the onEnter to be inside the element like above...

Comment: Consider a form with a submit-button

Comment: @xoxox Obviously...I wouldn't be asking then...

Comment: There's no "onenter" event, you've to detect a keyboard event, for example `keyup` to detect a key press. Then in the handler function check, if ENTER was hit. Notice, that if the input is in a form, the default action is to submit the form when pressing ENTER. In that case you probably have to prevent the default action.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Sure is:

```
<input name="text" type="text" onkeyup="callJavascriptFunction();">
```

You can also do it without the inline javascript:

```
<input id="myTextBox" name="text" type="text">
```

Then in your js file:

```
var myTextBox = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
myTextBox.addEventListener('keyup', function(){
    //do some stuff
});
```

---

Edit: If you're looking for enter press:

```
<input id="myTextBox" name="text" type="text">
```

Then in your js file:

```
var myTextBox = document.getElementById('myTextBox');
myTextBox.addEventListener('keypress', function(){
    if(e.keyCode == 13){//keyCode for enter
        //do some stuff
    }
});
```

Comment: ...onkeyup executes when ANY key is pressed on the keyboard.

Comment: I need onenter, when the enter key is pressed.

Comment: @frosty Google is for free

Answer (score 1):

Use the event **onchange**. You can do this on HTML:

```
<input onchange="fncDoThings()">
```

And your JS file can be like this:

```
function fncDoThings() {
    console.log('hello'); //just an example of things to do inside the function
};
```